# writing media query for different device sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to do some responsiveness fixes for certain devices.

For e.g for `Samsung Galaxy s5`, I need to change some code.

In chromes `inspect element`, It shows something like `360px X 640px`.

Now how do I write the specific code for this device?

For `iphone5` It shows `320px X 568px`.

I read somewhere that If I write like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
}
```

It'll work for all the devices but this doesn't seem to be working.

So overall for all these devices how do I write media query.

Please suggest.

**EDIT** : So After first comment's url, This is what I am doing

```
/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width: 375px) 
 and (max-device-width: 667px) 
 and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
 and (orientation: portrait) { 
  margin-left: 30px;
 }
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) can help

Comment: In this, what is the reason for having `landscape` and `portrait` together and then again having them separately?

Comment: That's a good observation. Unfortunately i don't have the answer. I can only guess that is an holistic approach to cover all possible devices and orientations but a more educated answer is surely needed

Answer (score 1):

Below are the all media queries for different resolution. So you can use it to make your website responsive.

```
    /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}



/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}



/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}



/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}



/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}



/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}



/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}



/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* iPhone 5 (portrait &amp; landscape)----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}



/* iPhone 5 (landscape)----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}



/* iPhone 5 (portrait)----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}
```

Comment: if the style is not applying then give !important to that css. If still not work then you have to give link or full code in fiddle or SO snippet.

Comment: you forget to select element in your css code above.

Comment: oops yes,

This is what I am trying, still not working.

`/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

    .tab-content .clear-style{
      margin-left:30px!important;
    }
}`

Comment: what exactly do you want. 
I want to apply `margin-left:30px` to one of my class. When I am applying via inspect element in inline, It works well but with this method of media query, It doesn't

Comment: so that's I want to see the issue. so i need link of your project..or just change min-device-width to min-width

Comment: I am not sure how exactly I can do that.. :s

Comment: Well, I got it working with something like 

`/*Galaxy s5 */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 360px) 
  and (max-width: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
    .galaxy-s5{
      margin-left:75px!important;
    }
}`

But I have to write for every devices. So I am not sure what's exactly wrong with `766px` thing

Comment: yes, localhost and Its rails so making a fiddle is very difficult. It is also using `masonary` plugin so ..

Comment: try to find issue by inspecting element in css part

Answer (score 0):

The media queries **do** work for phones, but you probably are missing this in your `head` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

Also, inside the `@media` tag, you need to specify the class that you want to give the styles to:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .my-div {
        /* Styles Here */
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your edit for your post, I saw that you were giving the styles in a wrong way. I updated my answer to show you how it should be done.

Comment: This is what I am trying, still not working.

`/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

    .tab-content .clear-style{
      margin-left:30px!important;
    }
}`

Comment: Try to change your @media line to be the same as the one in my answer.

Comment: that didn't work either.. I already have used exactly same earlier only. You can see that in my question itself

Comment: Could you post the full code somewhere then, would be a lot easier to find the problem.

Comment: Well, I got it working with something like 

`/*Galaxy s5 */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 360px) 
  and (max-width: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
    .galaxy-s5{
      margin-left:75px!important;
    }
}`

But I have to write for every devices. So I am not sure what's exactly wrong with `766px` thing

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you can go through the W3schools to get the clear understand on media queries

[Using media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

and after this you check [Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

here is the basic media query implementation

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col one">
            <p>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col two">
            <p>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. </p>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>


.col{
    color:#fff;
        float:left;
        margin:2%;
        width: 46%;
}
.one{
  background-color: #e95b33;
}

.two{
  background-color: #40b7d7;
}

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
        .col{
            float: none;
            margin:0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/TrentWalton/pen/kqxDy)